# Is Siri is new for every device with iOS 5, or just for the iPhone 4S?

Tags: ios, siri

I have iOS 5 on my iPod Touch 4, and I can't find Siri on it. Does it have Siri?

Comment: There have been some rumors that Siri will come to iPhone 4 in a future version of iOS.  But don't hold your breath.

Comment: I think it's likely we'll see Siri on the iPad 2 at some point, but not the iPhone 4. It's too much of a marketing tool, even if Siri will technically run just fine on an iPhone 4 (if that's even true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siri is only available on the iPhone 4S and only fully supported within the United States at the moment.

Unfortunately the page [here](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/siri.html) on Siri does not make that extremely clear, apart from only mentioning the iPhone 4S. I can't find an official source on the Apple site other then that page that specifically says Siri is only available on the 4S.

Siri supports various languages, however some functionality, like local business searches, will only work in the United States at the moment.

Comment: It *does* work in German, apparently. Not as perfect as in English, but it works.

Comment: @slhck Good point, updated my answer slightly for those to lazy to click and read the link.

Answer (score 0):

There was something the other day that said the software will technically run on the iphone 4 (with IOS 5), but the functionality requires access to Apple's servers...which you can currently only get with the 4S.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! For an answer like this to be useful, you need to cite sources. Please tell us where you got this information. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think an iPhone 4 can run it due to not having an A5 processor.

Comment: Can you link to the "something the other day" that you found?

Comment: It is (more likely) just a marketing thing. Apple is pushing people to buy the latest device.